# Property 'trim' does not exist on type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>

Tags: reactjs

I am getting below error in this line of code any help or suggestion where can i be wrong

Property 'trim' does not exist on type 'ChangeEvent'.ts(2339)

```
<SearchBox
      id={'SuggestionSearchBox'}
      placeholder={'Search ' + this.props.searchTitle}
      onSearch={newValue => this.onSearch(newValue)}
      onChange={newSearchText => {
        newSearchText.trim() !== '' ? this.showSuggestionCallOut() : this.hideSuggestionCallOut();
        this.setState({ searchText: newSearchText });
      }}
    />
 private showSuggestionCallOut() {
    this.setState({ isSuggestionDisabled: true });
  }
  private hideSuggestionCallOut() {
    this.setState({ isSuggestionDisabled: false });
  }
```

Comment: could you add **showSuggestionCallOut** function

Comment: added both function

Comment: 'trim' is string function, which means newSearchText is not a string. Console log what newSearchText is to find out why trim does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the onChange callback has a different signature than you assume.

The error seems to imply that the `newSearchText` argument is not a string as you think, but in fact a `ChangeEvent`, in which case you need to get your value like

```
onChange={e => {
  const newSearchText = e.target.value
  // rest of your code here
}
```

Or change the `onChange` type in the `SearchBox`, if that is within your control